# What is the electric field at the midpoint of the hypotenuse of a triangle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

[image: Electric Field at midpoint of hypotenuse figure]

Given, AB = BC = a and Charges at A, B and C are +q, +2q and +q respectively.
Found this problem in a textbook. I did it this way :

Charges at A and C will have no effect at this point since electric field due to them at D are equal and acts along opposite directions.

Distance BD will be $$\frac{a}{\sqrt2}$$

Now, electric field due to B on D is given by $$\frac{k.2q}{\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}$$ ,  where k is $$\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$$

This gives me the answer :
 $$\frac{k.4q}{a^2}$$

But the answer given on the textbook is :
$$\frac{k.q.2\sqrt2}{a^2}$$

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could it be that the book's answer is the _component_ of the E-field along each axis?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework site on check my answer; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is the slack use of vectors, what you found was the magnitude of electric field but you need to represent it in vector form as the question demands that. Your textbook answer is wrong as well. Change your reference book. 
That being said, your calculations are correct.

Comment: Really , change reference book. I have so far not seen a single perfect book without misprints.

Comment: Misprint would be if the vector representation was incorrect, this mistake showsthat its not a reliable source